# Possible to hide or filter parameters passed to redis from sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm sending a sidekiq job with a parameter that is confidential and I would like that parameter to be filtered so that no log or user is ever able to see it. Sidekiq itself does NOT output this parameter to its log, and the jobs runs in milliseconds so it would be tough to see it in the sidekiq web monitor.

But, if someone were to launch the redis-cli from a command line and run MONITOR then they would be able to see the parameters of the job passed in plain text.
Is there a way to filter this, so the parameters are blocked from the redis monitor?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is encrypt your job arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that's actually what the job I'm sending to Sidekiq is all about. I have an in-memory only global variable for an encryption key. In order for Sidekiq to know about this variable (since Sidekiq is running a separate instance) I need to send it a job with this value so it can set the global variable in Sidekiq. The basic idea behind this being that multiple people enter in their part of a shared secret to unlock the encryption key which no one on their own knows (split key / dual control PCI requirement).